# Ubuntu Hybrid Graphics automatic switch

Tags: ati, graphics, gpu, hybrid

My notebook have an integrated gpu (intel HD) and a discrete gpu (AMD Radeon 8850M). Looking into the ubuntu documantaion here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics I tried using switcheroo, but I'm really confused as I'm relatively new to Linux. I just want that my discrete gpu turn on when I'm with ac power and turn off when I unplug the power. Is that possible? Using the amd proprietary drivers is a no go since I have to reboot every time I want to switch between cards.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm using right now. I want my gpus to change dynamically in this way: ac power - discrete gpu, no ac power - integrated gpu

Comment: That's not what I want. I wanna know if it's possible for my cards to change without the need of rebooting